# mix elements of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array that contain 2 or more arrays (multidimensional)

```
array (
    array(
        'apple',
        'banans',
        'orange'
    ), 
    array(
        'green',
        'black',
        'yellow'
    ), array(
        'tasty'
    )
)
```

I need to get pairs of words - in fact array can contain x number of arrays

Output:

1. apple green tasty
2. apple black tasty
3. apple yellow tasty
4. banans green tasty
5. ...

Code looks something like this:

```
   foreach ($x as $k0 => $value0) {
        foreach ($x[$k0] AS $k1 => $value1) {
            foreach ($x[$k0 + 1] AS $k2 => $value2) {
                foreach ($x[$k0 + 2] AS $k3 => $value3) {
                    echo $m++ . '. ' . $value1 . ' ' . $value2 . ' ' . $value3;
                    echo '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And will output:

1. apple green tasty
2. apple black tasty
3. apple yellow tasty
4. banans green tasty
5. banans black tasty
6. banans yellow tasty
7. orange green tasty
8. orange black tasty
9. orange yellow tasty

But may be we have better sollution. In fact array can contain 2, 3, 4 arrays with list of words !

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for - do you need to output ALL permutations of one word from each array?

Comment: Pair of words how? Like $array[0][0] -> $array[1][0] (in a specific order? or random?!

Answer (score 3):

This will handle what you would like to do:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)